# How can I define a single pandas Interval?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For unit testing I need a single interval. However usually one uses [`interval_range()`, `from_arrays()`, `from_tuples()`, `from_breaks()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html#pandas.IntervalIndex)  to construct a new `IntervalIndex` containing several intervals. How can I get a single interval index?

Comment: You mean a single Interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single scalar [`Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html) object by specifying `left`, `right` and optionally `closed`:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.25.3'

In [2]: iv = pd.Interval(0, 1, closed='neither')

In [3]: iv
Out[3]: Interval(0, 1, closed='neither')
```

You can create an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) from a list of scalar `Interval` objects:

```py
In [4]: ii = pd.IntervalIndex([iv])

In [5]: ii
Out[5]: 
IntervalIndex([(0, 1)],
              closed='neither',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

In [6]: pd.IntervalIndex([iv, 2*iv, 3*iv])
Out[6]: 
IntervalIndex([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
              closed='neither',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

Comment: I've figured out yesterday that's as simple as that. Thx for the answer. Credits go to you.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.interval_range(start=0, end=5, periods=1)
```

This returns a single interval:

```
IntervalIndex([(0, 5]],
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.interval_range.html#pandas.interval_range), you can specify a `periods=1` parameter in `interval_range` to create an `IntervalIndex` object with a single interval.